# How to solve this exercise in java about Java Collection Framework

Tags: java, collections

The City class represents a city. The constructor accepts the city name, while the
**connect** method accepts another city and establishes a connection between the two (a street or another type of connection). All connections are bidirectional.
The **getConnections** method returns the collection of cities directly connected to it. The
**isConnected** method takes as argument another city and returns true if it is connected to this
directly or indirectly (i.e., via an arbitrary number of connections).

Example

```
City n = new City("Napoli"), r = new City("Roma"), s = new City
("Salerno"), p = new City("Parigi");
n.connect(s);
n.connect(r);
Collection<City> r_conn = r.getConnections();
System.out.println(r_conn);//Napoli
System.out.println(r .isConnected(s));//true
System.out.println(r .isConnected(p));//false
```

I really need some help with the connect and isConnected method. Specifically how can I enter a two-sided connection between two cities?How can I then calculate if one city is indirectly connected to another?

**My Code**

```
public class City {
    private String name;
    private Set<City> connections;

    public City(String name){
        this.name = name;
        connections = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public void connect(City city){
        //connetti city a questa città
        connections.add(city);
    }

    public Collection<City> getConnections(){
        return connections;
    }

    public boolean isConnected(City city){
        return connections.contains(city);
    }

    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        City n = new City("Napoli"), r = new City("Roma"), s = new City
        ("Salerno"), p = new City("Parigi");
        n.connect(s);
        n.connect(r);
        Collection<City> r_conn = r.getConnections();
        System.out.println(r_conn);
        System.out.println(r .isConnected(s));
        System.out.println(r .isConnected(p));
    }

}
```

Comment: The type of structure you are talking about here, with nodes and edges, is called a graph. I'm not going to answer your question because StackOverflow is not for homework questions - but if you google "How to traverse a graph" or "How to tell if graph nodes are connected" you'll find answers.

Outside of a homework context you shouldn't do this yourself. Find a Graph library and use that. Guava has a good one: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/GraphsExplained

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 2):

Usually these kinds of exercises are intended to make you think, so this isn't always true, but: Sometimes just... do the simplest thing and write the spec into code.

Here, the spec says that if you run `a.connect(b)`, then both a is connected to b and b is connected to a. So just write that, then:

```
public void connect(City city) {
    this.connections.add(city);
    city.connections.add(this);
}
```

This adds the provided city to your set of connections, and adds yourself to the set of connections in the provided city.

`isConnected` is the more complicated beast. You'll need to perform traversal. That's an entire study on its own. There are a number of common pitfalls (getting stuck forever, eventually resulting in a StackOverflowError, for example), and a number of common ways to tackle the problem.

One solution:

- Start with an empty set. This tracks all cities you've already checked.
- Then go through all your connections. For each connection, if you're already checked it, `continue;`. If the connection is the intended target, great, `return true;` on the spot.
- Otherwise, add the city to the 'I checked this' set, then go through all *its* connections using the same algorithm (which will again use the same algorithm). HINT: This involves recursion (calling your own method), or alternatively an operation stack.

Search the web for tutorials on recursive algorithms or path finding algorithms. Following such tutorials + the above guidelines will let you know exactly how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

*How can I enter a two-sided connection between two cities?*
Method `connect` needs to be modified as @rzwitserloot suggested earlier:

```java
public void connect(City city) {
    // connection to the city
    connections.add(city);
    // reverse connection from the city
    city.connections.add(this);
}
```

*How can I then calculate if one city is indirectly connected to another?*
Also, this is recursive implementation of the approach suggested by @rzwitserloot:

```java
public boolean isConnected(City city) {
    return isConnected(city, new HashSet<>());
}

private boolean isConnected(City city, Set<City> checked) {
    if (this == city || connections.contains(city)) {
        return true;
    }
    checked.add(this);
    
    for (City nested : connections) {
        if (checked.contains(nested)) {
            continue;
        }
        return nested.isConnected(city, checked);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Test:

```java
City neapol = new City("Napoli"), rome = new City("Roma"), salerno = new City("Salerno"), paris = new City("Parigi");
neapol.connect(salerno);
neapol.connect(rome);
Collection<City> rome_conn = rome.getConnections();
System.out.println(rome_conn);
System.out.println("Rome connected to Salerno? " + rome.isConnected(salerno));
System.out.println("Rome connected to Paris? " + rome.isConnected(paris));

salerno.connect(paris);
System.out.println("Paris connected to Neapol? " + paris.isConnected(neapol));
```

Output:

```
[Napoli]
Rome connected to Salerno? true
Rome connected to Paris? false
Paris connected to Neapol? true
```